# Field dependencies/Dependent picklist

Tags: picklist, dependent-picklist, field-dependencies

Hii wondering if this is possible. Can I have a value default in a dependent pick list based on the controlling field selection (I only have 1 value in the dependent field). So can this be defaulted somehow? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. If it makes sense functionally, you can make the dependent picklist as required, then its value will be defaulted.

Comment: Thank you! How do I make it required?

Comment: Under "Fields & Relationships" for that object, open the dependent picklist field, click on Edit and check the option "Required"

Answer (score 0):

Go to the respective object page layout and make the dependent picklist field as mandatory and save page layout.

Lightning Navigation: Setup --> Object manager --> Object --> Page layouts.

[image]

While creating a record, select controlling field value  then dependent field value will be auto updated. Refer the below screenshot.

[image]

**Note:** Lightning, it works for new records.